# Oracle Apex 5.1 Dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

how to Dynamic SQL before report to users in Apex 5.1?
my query is:

```
declare
    q varchar2(4000);
begin
    q := 'select * from tb1 t';
    if :Param1 is not null then
        q := q || ' where t.name = :Param1';
    end if;

return q;
end;
```

***:Param1*** is optional for users.

I want if **:Param1 is null** then my query execute **without** any where clause.
otherwise set where clause in my query.

the point is my Apex is Version 5.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If that query is used as a a source for a report region, then you don't have to use dynamic SQL, but a simple `OR` condition:

```
select * 
from tb1 t
where (t.name = :param1 or :param1 is null)
```

The same would work elsewhere too.

Comment: I want if :Param1 is null then my query execute without any where clause. otherwise set where clause in my query.

Comment: That's exactly what such a WHERE clause does.

Answer (score 0):

you can use such a way below by using `rowtype` and `type` keywords for `whole row` and `column` values respectively :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
    q         varchar2(4000);
    rt        tb1%rowtype;
    i_name    tb1.name%type := 'Mohammad';
    o_surname tb1.surname%type;
begin
    q := 'select * from tb1 t';
    if i_name is not null then
        q := q || ' where ( t.name = :Param1 or :Param1 is null )'; 
    end if;
  execute immediate q into rt using i_name, i_name; 
 -- "i_name" appears twice because of ":Param1" appears twice in the string "q"
  o_surname := rt.surname;
  dbms_output.put_line(rt.surname);
end;

Taleshi
```

*since there's only one parameter, then `:Param1` is matched with `i_name`. If we had more than one parameter, then all should be matched in the appearance order of the bind parameters in the sql string with comma seperated variables such as `i_name, ....` in the `using` list.*

Comment: @MohammadTaleshi ok, no need to shout, by the way seems more than a problem related with PL/SQL.

Comment: It's not working. because the where clause finally check in query with or without null value.

Comment: @MohammadTaleshi Excuse me, now I've fixed.

Comment: Generally in APEX you would not execute the query but let APEX run it to generate the report output.